# Issue with @media CSS not working in portrait mode only?

Tags: css, mobile

I have been struggling with the iPad portrait view of a post grid on my site. The grid looks fine in all other view except for this one, where the grid appears on the far right-hand side of the container.

The theme's (Alexandra) CSS is as follows:

`@media only screen and (max-width: 941px) and (min-width: 768px).container {width: 726px;}`

I've tried to modify this by using:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 941px) and (orientation:portrait) .container {width:510px;}
```

And:

```
 @media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 941px) and (orientation:portrait) { .container {width:510px !important;}}
```

Also:

```
 @media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 941px) and (orientation:portrait) { .container {margin-right: 200px;}
```

As well as several other configurarions and nothing happens. Any ideas on what I'm missing or why this isn't working or changing anything? Thank you so much for reading! Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Comment: have you added meta tags ?? <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

Comment: I haven't, no. However, I am using a plugin (Reactive Pro Advanced Search and Filter) and other @media queries are working--just not this particular one.

I don't see this tag on the page template...forgive my ignorance (I am new to working with responsive code like this) is that where I would put it? If so, any particular place? If not, where? Thank you for responding!

Comment: Okay, I just added that code to the page template and...it fixed the issue of the grid being pushed to the right of the container! Thanks for the info, much appreciated!

Comment: So meta solved your problem??

Comment: Yes, to the extent that I was able to change the page width and move the grid. I can now also make other changes. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML5 introduced a method to let web designers take control over the viewport, through the `<meta>` tag.

So you should add to index.html this meta:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```